# correct format for ssh authorized_keys2 file

Tags: ssh

The sshd manual page is confusing me, and others administering our systems.

Under "AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT" there is the statement:

> The options field is optional; its presence is determined by whether the line starts with a number*.

Under what circumstance would a line start with a number? Perhaps the man page is inter-mixing up Protocol 1 and Protocol 2 info.

Later on we have an example authorized_keys file, which I assume is Protocol 2 style since is has a keytype looking field. However it is multi-line, with options on the lines following the key.

Looking around I see use of both the single and multiline form. I suspect the multiline form is invalid.

Is this correct or not, or are there some versions that do allow this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Under what circumstance would a line start with a number? Perhaps the man page is inter-mixing up Protocol 1 and Protocol 2 info.

The public keys for SSHv1 protocol were not base64 encoded and therefore started with number. The `2` appendix to `authorized_keys2` does not mean the SSHv2 keys, but it is just a second file with the keys. The semantics of both files is the same and can (not anymore after removing SSHv1 code) contain both SSHv1 and SSHv2 keys mixed.

Current version of manual page does not have this sentence anymore:

> Public keys consist of the following space-separated fields: options, keytype, base64-encoded key, comment.  **The options field is optional.**  The keytype is “ecdsa-sha2-nistp256”, “ecdsa-sha2-nistp384”, “ecdsa-sha2-nistp521”, “ssh-ed25519”, “ssh-dss” or “ssh-rsa”; the comment field is not used for anything (but may be convenient for the user to identify the key).

The expected format of the public key is also described above (was probably not in your old version).